# AttributeError - But Dataframe has the attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame and it won't recognize the column with the following error message: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'B_N'`

df1

```
Type   B_N
A      AT74
A      BQT1
C      0
```

The line of code that errors is:

```
df1.B_N[df1['B_N'] == '0'] = np.nan
```

Basically I want any value with in Column B_N that is 0 to be a NaN value.

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix this by using df.rename after importing the data set.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you think is 'B_N' may not be 'B_N'. There might be spaces around it.

Can you do a df.columns and check if it's exactly 'B_N'?

Comment: I did the df.columns and did not see any spaces.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what I change the name too.  I've tried different names and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Can you paste the output of df.columns here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like :

```
df1['B_N']=df1['B_N'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

Example :

```
>>> df1=pd.DataFrame({'B_N':['wrd','wrfe', 0], 'Type':['A', 'A', 'C']})
>>> df1
    B_N Type
0   wrd    A
1  wrfe    A
2     0    C
>>> df1['B_N']=df1['B_N'].replace(0, np.nan)
>>> df1
    B_N Type
0   wrd    A
1  wrfe    A
2   NaN    C
```

Comment: I tried doing this but now I have a KeyError: 'B_N'

Comment: can you edit your post an post your code where you create `df1` ?

Comment: I'm using this as an example since the actual code.  The actual code is quite long.  I do change the value of the Column from 'B N' to 'B_N' if that makes a difference.  Other than that it's a two dataframes merging beforehand with pd.concat to create df1.  BN dtype is an object

Comment: I edit my post with an example, but please edit your post to make understand how is really your `df1` structure. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve